# Prove that a certain block combination of totally unimodular matrices is totally unimodular

Tags: matrices, total-unimodularity, unimodular-matrices

I conjecture the following.

Given three rectangular matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that the following two block matrices $
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A & B \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$
and
$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A \\
    C \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$
are totally unimodular, the following matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}
    A & B \\
    C & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$
is totally unimodular.

Can you help me to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a counterexample, i'm sorry.

$
\det 
\left[
\begin{array}{c c | c}
1  &  0 &  1 \\
0  &  1 & 1 \\ \hline
-1 & -1 & 0 
\end{array}
\right]
= 2
$

Comment: Indeed, perhaps we can use Laplace expansion, in this case. Let me think a little bit more.

Comment: @maxdan94 0-matrix can also be rectangular in your case?

Comment: @maxdan94 I changed a bit my answer in order to cover the case of not square B'

Comment: no, currently, it doesn't work.

Comment: This discussion is about my old answer, should we consider to remove the comments ?